Immediate break after input using switch or if
I am learning C right now and im at the very beginning.
Here's my code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

char operator;
double num1;
double num2;
double result;

printf("\n Enter an operator");
scanf("%c", &operator);

printf("Enter number 1:");
scanf("%lf", &num1);

printf("Enter number 2:");
scanf("%lf", &num2);


switch(operator){
    break;
    case '+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        printf("\nresult: %.0lf", result);
        break;
      case '-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        printf("\nresult: %.0lf", result);
        break;
      case '*':
        result = num1 * num2;
        printf("\nresult: %.0lf", result);
        break;
      case '/':
        result = num1 / num2;
        printf("\nresult: %lf", result);
        break;
    default:
       printf("%c is not valid", operator);
}
    return 0;
}

If I enter an operator other than / / * + or -, I get 'x is not valid' after entering the numbers, so I need your help with this. If I enter the wrong operator at the very beginning, how do I end the code right there so I don't have to enter that number?
I thought of using break func. or if-else but, I am not able to do that.
Thanks for your help!
I want the code to immediately display the 'wrong operator' error if I enter the wrong operator.

There's a spurious break; in the current version of the code. Remove that. Also, indent the body of the function consistently. Indentation shows (but does NOT affect) the structure of the code. Your readers will thank you for making things as clear as possible.

Does this answer your question? Input validation in C


I thought of using break func. or if-else but, I am not able to do that.

Are you allowed to use any if statements? Or is it simply that you cant use an if-else to check if input operator equals each of valid operator separately?
If you can use one if statement you can use strchr(), which checks if a character (input) is found in a string (valid operators):
const char *valid_chars = "//*+-";
printf("\n Enter an operator");
scanf("%c", &operator);

if (!strchr(valid_chars, operator)) {
     printf("Wrong operator");
}


Yes, I am allowed to use any statement, i'm just a casual learner :D
I haven't heard of const or strchr as you mentioned. Will look them deeply. Thanks for your help and effort!

Don't need two / in the valid characters. Forward slash doesn't need to be escaped.

The code should probably note that scanf() leaves the newline in the input buffer and use " %c" to scan the operator.  It isn't critical while the input is failing, but it becomes critical when a loop is added to do more than one calculation.

There's also no benefit to list / twice in the valid_chars.  And using static const char valid_chars[] = "/*+-"; is more economical (though not by a lot).
